# database column as parameter argument

Tags: android, database, sqlite

how do I write a method for sqlite where i can put the column i want to update as a parameter of the method?

for example something like this, updateThisRow(A4, "test string");

where the A4 is the column name used

variables declared in the database class;

```
 // variables for LARGE_TANK_CHECK_RESULT
    public static final String A0 = "a0";
    public static final String A1 = "a1";
    public static final String A2 = "a2";
    public static final String A3 = "a3";
    public static final String A4 = "a4";
    public static final String A5 = "a5";
    public static final String A6 = "a6";
    public static final String A7 = "a7";........
```

function i was using before that requires all the columns to be updated, not what i was looking for.

```
 public void insertNewRowLargeTank(String[] a, String[] b){

                        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                        contentValues.put(A0, a[0]);
                        contentValues.put(A1, a[1]);
                        contentValues.put(A2, a[2]);
                        contentValues.put(A3, a[3]);
                        contentValues.put(A4, a[4]);
                        contentValues.put(A5, a[5]);
                        contentValues.put(A6, a[6]);
                        contentValues.put(A7, a[7]);
                        contentValues.put(A8, a[8]);
                        contentValues.put(A9, a[9]);
                        contentValues.put(A10, a[10]);
                        contentValues.put(A11, a[11]);
                        contentValues.put(A12, a[12]);
                        contentValues.put(A13, a[13]);
                        contentValues.put(A14, a[14]);
                        contentValues.put(A15, a[15]);
                        contentValues.put(A16, a[16]);
                        contentValues.put(A17, a[17]);
                        contentValues.put(A18, a[18]);
                        contentValues.put(A19, a[19]);
                        contentValues.put(A20, a[20]);
                        contentValues.put(A21, a[21]);
                        contentValues.put(A22, a[22]);
                        contentValues.put(A23, a[23]);
                        contentValues.put(A24, a[24]);
                        contentValues.put(A25, a[25]);
                        contentValues.put(A26, a[26]);
                        contentValues.put(A27, a[27]);
                        contentValues.put(A28, a[28]);
                        contentValues.put(A29, a[29]);
                        contentValues.put(A30, a[30]);
                        contentValues.put(A31, a[31]);
                        contentValues.put(A32, a[32]);
                        contentValues.put(A33, a[33]);
                        contentValues.put(A34, a[34]);
                        contentValues.put(A35, a[35]);
                        contentValues.put(A36, a[36]);
                        contentValues.put(A37, a[37]);
                        contentValues.put(A38, a[38]);
                        contentValues.put(A39, a[39]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Columns and tables are fixed in a an internally prepared sqlite statement. Therefore, you can't do binding with columns, as opposed to binding new values for multiple calls to the statements.

If you want to dynamically build sql statements, use a `StringBuilder`, or create a formatted string for `String.format()` and re-use that every time you execute your statement.